# GridView's first Item is not showing up

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to add gridView and customize its adapter.

But the first item does not appear, and item click listener also not works.
[image: myImage]

Is my code incorrect?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView text;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_mission_private_item, parent, false);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth() / 3, parent.getHeight() / 2));
        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
        convertView.setTag(text);
    } else {
        text = (TextView) convertView.getTag();
    }
    text.setText(mData.get(position).first);
    if (mData.get(position).second)
        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    return convertView;
}
```

edit: full source

```
public class MissionPrivateGvAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
public ArrayList<Pair<String, Boolean>> mData;

public MissionPrivateGvAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, ArrayList<Pair<String, Boolean>> data) {
    mLayoutInflater = inflater;
    mData = data;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position).first;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView text;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_mission_private_item, parent, false);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth() / 3, parent.getHeight() / 2));
        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
        convertView.setTag(text);
    } else {
        text = (TextView) convertView.getTag();
    }
    text.setText(mData.get(position).first);
    if (mData.get(position).second)
        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: what do you meant by mData.get(position).first? and post the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width and height of parent view is zero when you first invoke getView method.Maybe you can obtain screen content width and height to set their values.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));